# displaying ACF Repeater Fields in Backend sorted by a subfield

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields

I'm facing a challenge :-)

The goal: displaying ACF Repeater Fields sorted by a subfield in the backend. In the frontend, the fields are sorted using PHP, but I also want to have the same view in the post-edit mode.

Unfortunately, this code doesn't work in functions.php:

```
    function sort_acf_repeater_in_admin($value, $post_id, $field) {
    // Überprüfen, ob wir uns im Admin-Bereich befinden
    if(is_admin()) {
        // Überprüfen, ob es sich um das richtige Feld handelt
        if($field['name'] === 'bestfilm') {
            // Überprüfen, ob $value ein Array ist
            if(is_array($value)) {
                usort($value, function($a, $b) {
                    return -strcmp($a['regie'], $b['regie']);  // Umgekehrt zum Aufsteigend sortieren
                });
            }
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
add_filter('acf/load_value/type=repeater', 'sort_acf_repeater_in_admin', 10, 3);
```

I have also tried

```
// functions.php
function enqueue_custom_admin_scripts() {
    global $pagenow;

    // Stelle sicher, dass der Code nur auf der Post-Edit-Seite geladen wird
    if ($pagenow === 'post.php' || $pagenow === 'post-new.php') {
        // Enqueue jQuery
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

        // Füge benutzerdefiniertes JavaScript hinzu
        wp_enqueue_script('custom-admin-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom-admin-scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    }
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_admin_scripts');
```

with

```
//custom-admin-scripts.js

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Stelle sicher, dass das ACF-Plugin geladen ist
    if (typeof acf === 'undefined') {
        return;
    }

    // Spezifiziere den Namen des Repeater-Fields
    var repeaterFieldName = 'bestfilm';

    // Spezifiziere den Namen des Subfields, nach dem sortiert werden soll
    var subfieldName = 'regie';

    // Finde das Repeater-Field
    var repeaterField = $('[data-name="' + repeaterFieldName + '"]').closest('.acf-field-repeater');

    // Finde alle Repeater-Gruppen
    var repeaterGroups = repeaterField.find('.acf-row');

    // Sortiere die Repeater-Gruppen nach dem Subfield
    repeaterGroups.sort(function(a, b) {
        var subfieldA = $(a).find('[data-name="' + subfieldName + '"]').val();
        var subfieldB = $(b).find('[data-name="' + subfieldName + '"]').val();

        // Vergleiche die Werte des Subfields und sortiere aufsteigend
        return subfieldA.localeCompare(subfieldB);
    });

    // Hänge die sortierten Gruppen wieder an das DOM an
    repeaterGroups.each(function() {
        repeaterField.find('.acf-fields').prepend($(this));
    });
});
```

I would appreciate any tips on how to achieve this. The view in the backend doesn't need to be saved in the database; having the view is enough.

Bacio

Comment: My ACF is rusty, but that looks sensible enough to me. I'd try debugging this if you can, e.g. add lots of console.log() calls to make sure your code is getting called with the right field names, you're seeing the values you expect, etc. Or try stepping through in your browser's debug tools too.

Comment: I'd hope there was a way to sort the values at the point ACF is reading them for the UI though, so you wouldn't have to do it after-the-fact in script. Maybe worth asking them for help too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ho trovato il coniglio (I found the rabbit)! This sorts and synchronizes frontend and backwend (post edit view).

```
function my_acf_load_value( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
    
    // vars
    $order = array();
    
    // bail early if no value
    if( empty($value) ) {
        
        return $value;
    }
    
    // populate order
    foreach( $value as $i => $row ) {
        $order[ $i ] = $row['field_606af7xxxxxx']; // Ersetzen Sie 'field_XXXXX' durch den tatsächlichen Schlüssel des 'regie'-Feldes.
    }
    
    // multisort
    array_multisort( $order, SORT_ASC, $value ); // Ändern Sie SORT_DESC in SORT_ASC, wenn Sie aufsteigend sortieren möchten.
    
    // return   
    return $value;
}

add_filter('acf/load_value/name=bestfilm', 'my_acf_load_value', 10, 3); // Ändern Sie 'scores' in 'bestfilm'.
```